# Array_merge() two array into one not working

Tags: php, array-merge

I have problem wiht array_merge():

First array:

```
$array1=array(
[0]=>array(["key1"]=>"value1",["key2"]=>"value2",["key3"]=>"value3")
);
```

Second array:

```
$array2=array(["key4"]=>"value4",["key5"]=>"value5",["key6"]=>"value6");
```

And I need merge this arrays to one like this:

```
$array1=array(
    [0]=>array(["key1"]=>"value1",["key2"]=>"value2",
    ["key3"]=>"value3",["key4"]=>"value4",["key5"]=>"value5",["key6"]=>"value6"));
```

But when use:

```
$array3=array_merge($array1,$array2);
var_dump($array3);
```

var_dump return this:

```
 array(
    [0]=>array(["key1"]=>"value1",["key2"]=>"value2",
    ["key3"]=>"value3") ["key4"]=>"value4",["key5"]=>"value5",["key6"]=>"value6");
```

And don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: Then you just want to merge the first subArray from the first array with the second array, nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array3=array(array_merge($array1[0],$array2));
```

you have to merge the inner array, not the outer one.

https://3v4l.org/dCm2F

Answer (score 1):

Merging the first element from first array with the second one, may help:

```
$array3 = array();
$array3[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2);
```